# I have problem with deploying my token to Goerli testnet

Tags: tokens, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, goerli

I have an issue with deploying smart contract on Goerli network.
When I trying to run the contract I get Error

```
Error HH100: Network goerli doesn't exist
```

Here is example of my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract FICEToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Token", "TKN") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + 60;

  const lockedAmount = hre.ethers.parseEther("0.001");

  const lock = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Token", [unlockTime], {
    value: lockedAmount,
  });

  await lock.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    `Lock with ${ethers.formatEther(
      lockedAmount
    )}ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.target}`
  );
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

hardhat.config.js

```
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle')

const PRIVATE_KEY = 'PRIVATE KEY'
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161'

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts:[`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      chainID: 5,
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  };
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the command you are using to run deploy.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Developer Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/).

Based on your query, there are a couple of issues to address:

1. The deploy script you're using appears to be the default sample from Hardhat, not tailored for your specific smart contract.
2. You seem to be using an outdated version of Hardhat.

Let's resolve these step-by-step:

#### Update Hardhat

First, update to the latest version of Hardhat. Follow the [official documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#installation) for guidance.

#### Initialize a New Project

Create a [new Hardhat project](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#quick-start). During initialization, opt to install `hardhat-toolbox`.

#### Install Dependencies

Ensure you've installed OpenZeppelin contracts:

```sh
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

#### Smart contract

The smart contract you posted is ok.

#### Configure Hardhat

Add your private keys and RPC to the following.

> I strongly recommend using `dotevn` to get the sensitive info from a `.env` file.

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const PRIVATE_KEY = "PRIVATE_KEY";
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = "YOUR_RPC_URL";

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.20",
};
```

For more on using `.env` files, refer to this [guide](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/how-to-store-your-web3-dapp-secrets-guide-to-environment-variables).

#### Deploy Script

Here's a sample `deploy.js`:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  console.log("Deploying contract...");

  // Deploy the contract
  const FICEToken = await hre.ethers.deployContract("FICEToken");

  // Wait for the transaction to be mined
  await FICEToken.waitForDeployment();

  // Log the address of the deployed contract
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", FICEToken.target);
}

// Execute the script and handle errors
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Remember that this will only work with the same smart contract you have in your post (because of the name).

If you change the name of the contract, edit it in this line:

```js
hre.ethers.deployContract("FICEToken");
```

#### Compilation and Deployment

Compile your smart contract:

```sh
npx hardhat compile
```

Deploy it:

```sh
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
```

It will return a result like this:

```sh
Deploying contract...
Contract deployed to: 0xa804D8845263719e2E9bff14930cE738950FB623
```

#### Additional Note

For testing, consider using the [Sepolia network](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/goerli-to-sepolia-transition) as it's recommended for smart contracts and DApps. Just FIY :)

Feel free to reach out if you need more help!

Comment: Thank you so much) Now everything works fine)